# What is used as unique id of customer in Web Reccomendations request

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

Web Recommendations Script looks something like this, it either returns a JSON or a function that appends website HTML:

```
https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/MID/page/recommend.json
https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/MID/page/recommend.js
```

I want to understand what unique id is passed when requesting these recommendations. For example - if I make a simple JQuery AJAX GET request by client browser for JSON, what I need to do/add to this request to make sure that output will be correct.

I've checked console when sending for these and I can't seem to find any unique id passed in body or header, which leads me to belive that IP address is used as unique id. Is there someone that can confirm that? If it's IP is there a way to explicitly declare user id same way as in email recommendations to display correct recommendations outside of client browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MID value will be your Business Unit ID.

When you watch inside Einstein implementation instructions in salesforce marketing cloud you will find an explanation that you have to pass the "email" parameter inside recommendation strings to make this recommendation call unique for a "contact / subscriber".

That said the email parameter is named missleading. It should have better been named like uuid or id od something like that. I would strongly recommend to pass a unique value which does not change for a contact/customer.

If this answer is not what you have been searching for please comment under this question, because i am not sure if this is what you expected.

Therefore your recommendation string of the business unit 987654321 for the customer with the id 12345 will be https://987654321.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/987654321/page/recommend.js?email=12345.

Comment: Hey Johannes, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks. I encountered other issue - when I try to request JSON with AJAX I'm getting blocked by CORS. Is there a way for SF to allow access for selected domains? Or maybe you know other way to get this data with AJAX?

Comment: The problem you face is not based on Salesforce and cannot be changed on the salesforce side. Your shop needs to be changed that Salesforce calls can be done. It is a security feature of modern browsers. Contact your development team of your shop ;)